# Change color of span on focus of input in another span

Tags: html, css

I need to change the background color of a span using css when an input field in another span is focused.

```
<p class="some">
<span class="one">Name</span> 
<span class="two"> <input type="text" name="fname"> </span>
</p>
```

Here is the css:

```
.one
 { background-color: red; }
```

I tried doing this:

```
.two:focus + .one
 {background-color-black;}
```

but its not working.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: You can not do it by css.

Comment: If you want to change color `.two` you can modify your html structure.

Comment: You can only select an adjacent sibling that comes after, not before.  So you can't target `one` as a sibling of `two`, but you could target `two` as a sibling of `one`. Also, the class `.two` doesn't refer to the input box here, it refers to the `span` which isn't what would be focused.  You'll need JavaScript for this.

Comment: javascript then? I need to change the color of `.one` not `.two`

Comment: @Sumaiya Yes, you can

Comment: Jquery: `$('input[name=fname]').focus( function (){ $(this).parent().siblings ('.one').css('color','red')});`

Comment: @alirezasafian your jquery solution works! thank you!

Comment: @Sumaiya You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `:focus-within`,
It worked for me.

This is a document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

```css
.one { float: left; }
input { margin: 0 0 0 5px; }
.some:focus-within .one { background: red; }
```

```html
<p class="some">
<span class="one">Name</span> 
<span class="two"> <input type="text" name="fname"> </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript:

Html:

```
<p class="some">
<span class="one">Name</span> 
<span class="two"> <input type="text" name="fname" onfocus="changeColor()"> </span>
</p>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function changeColor() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0].style.backgroundColor="black";
 }
</script>
```

Css:

```
.one
 { background-color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind elements order, try this snippet:

```css
.one { float: left; }
input[name="fname"] { margin: 0 0 0 5px; }
input[name="fname"]:focus + .one { background: khaki; }
```

```html
<p class="some">
  <input type="text" name="fname"/>
  <span class="one">Name</span> 
</p>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ilyabogdanov/2kyps2hn/)

Answer (score 0):

Another javascript solution, using classes, and also handles the input loosing focus:

```js
function getFocus() {
    var one = document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0];
    one.className = one.className + " one-focused";
}

function looseFocus() {
    var one = document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0];
    one.className = one.className.replace("one-focused", "");
}
```

```css
.one { background-color: red; }
.one-focused { background-color: black; }
```

```html
<p class="some">
<span class="one">Name</span> 
<span class="two"> <input type="text" name="fname" onfocus="getFocus()"  onblur="looseFocus()"> </span>
</p>
```

This has some fairly obvious flaws, but works in this case. You may want to loop through all classes, or use id's instead of classes. If you are using jQuery then this becomes slightly simpler, but I have left this using standard javascript and only changing the background of the first element in the document.